# I am getting lot of errors while setting up google maps API in my android Application

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to integrate google maps API in my android application but getting lot of errors. I went through lot of questions online for solving the problem but couldn't find a single post which could help me. For this specific errors lot of solution recommended to toggle the offline button and I have already done that but it didn't help me. So anyone could help me in giving different solution. I am hereby attaching my build.gradle file for your reference

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mppolice"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'


}
```

Following is the list of error I am getting while building my application

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0.
```

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version (18.0.2)? ```com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2```

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes, tried but same error.

Comment: I think gradle sync offline mode in your studio... Check that

Comment: @GobuCSG No, it's in online mode only. I made sure of that.

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start) documentation? Here it states that there is a version 18.1.0.

Comment: has this been resolved?